# Installing RVM in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rvm

I have problem with ruby and decided to do a fresh installation of rvm and rails...

When i try to install rvm by `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`  ,
 i get the following error

curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted

when i change the https as http, i get .

syntax error near unexpected token `<'
bash: line 1:`'

I tried it in a system wide proxy .. then removed system wide proxy and configured in 01proxy and still got the same result.

Where am i going wrong in installing this??

I installed using the same command a few weeks back and it worked.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your proxy is doing something with the request.

You can try to download the installer script by other means. First try to enter that URL in your web browser. If you go to a page starting with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` then your can just save it (right click -> Save as / Save page as) as "rvm-installer".

If it does not work you can try to download the script by its full url:

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer
```

After that you can execute it:

```
$ cat /path/to/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```

Hope it helps.